# android background image on background image

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I have **Activity** with **background image**, and the image is bright color.
My TextView, EditText and others components is bright too.
I want to create more background image(or other way to create white background with **Rounded Corners**) on the current background image, it's look like:
[image]

thank u

Comment: make your parent layout to be FrameLayout make it background darker, now take another layout say `_sublayout` in this layout, put all your controls in this layout and provide it rounded white bg.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the white drawable like this and set it as background to activity layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
 >

<solid 
    android:color="#FFFFFF"
    />
<corners
    android:radius="5dp"
    />

</shape>
```